# Checking for Char/Int

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop, evaluation

Alright so I am doing an assignment and am getting frustrated. The assignment wants me to ask the user for a number then say if the number is even or odd, but if the user types "done" the program will exit.

So my question is how do you check the input for character/int at the same time, then decide which it is.

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//    
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
bool isEven(int userAnswer);
using namespace std;
int userAnswer;

int main()
{
    cout << "Which number would you like to check?" << endl;
    cin >> userAnswer; 

    if (isEven(userAnswer) == false)
    {
        cout << userAnswer << " is a odd number." << endl;
    }   
    else if (isEven(userAnswer) == true)
    {
        cout << userAnswer << " is a even number." << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

bool isEven(int userAnswer)
{
    if (userAnswer % 2 == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int userAnswer;` should be declared inside `main` instead of a global variable, and you don't need the `else if` but just an `else` since there are only two possibilities from the function call (`== false` and the negation of that. More idiomatic would be `!isEven(userAnswer)`).

Comment: I sugest you to check the "done" string first, then if it's not done, convert the string to int and do the even/odd check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read into a string (which works in both cases), then parse the string yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Read into a `std::string` and exit if `done` is in the string. Otherwise convert to `int` and carry on as you are.  Hint: see `std::stoi`

Comment: No. *Don't* use `stoi`, use `std::stringstream` and check if the insertion into an integer failed.

Comment: Why do you prefer `std::stringstream`?

Comment: It's much more type safe and from an interface standpoint works just like `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Comment: I don't understand why it's more type safe. Do you have a reference pls?

Comment: I stand corrected. I was under the impression that `stoi` worked like the old `atoi`, (and etc.) functions (i.e. horribly). Seems `stoi` and the similar `stol` and `stoll` were added for C++11 and are robust. +1.